# Amazon SES sends email from 000-dsds-dss@amazonses.com instead configured domain<xyz@domain.com>

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

For some users, Amazon SES sends email from 0000-3232-ddsd-sas@amazonses.com domain instead configured domain

Is there any configuration to be done in SES side to allow sending message with correct domain to reported users?

Comment: When you say "For some users", do you mean this issue occurs for few IAM users? Is it working for other users? Is the custom mail from domain in verified status?

Comment: Not IAM users, for all the users belong to some specific domain. It's working for users in some other domain.